# how to change the background color or the text color of the whole site when clicking on a color ? Angular

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript

How can I change the background color of the whole site or the text color when I click on a color from one component to another?
I need to use the Output decorator but how ?

**style.component.html**

```
<div>
    <h2>background colors</h2>
    <div class="theme-options">
        <div class="theme-white"></div>
        <div class="theme-blue"></div>
        <div class="theme-orange"></div>
        <div class="theme-green"></div>
    </div>
    <hr>
    <h2>text Color</h2>
    <div class="theme-options">
        <div class="theme-white"></div>
        <div class="theme-blue"></div>
        <div class="theme-orange"></div>
        <div class="theme-green"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**app.component.html**

```
<app-signin></app-signin>
<app-style></app-style>
```

Comment: easiest way is to use JS to add a class to the body that applies changes presetted within the css

Comment: I'm a beginner, how can I do it? @tacoshy

Answer (score -1):

I just made a cut down version for demonstration for the `background-color`. It works the very same for `text-color`.

**Step 1:**
We need to add an unique `onclick` trigger to the buttons/boxes. So if they are pressed, they will fire a script.

**Step 2:**
We add a function that removes all possible classes to change the `background-color` by using `document.querySelector("body").classList.remove("class");`. That will remove possible a class from the body tag.

**Step 3:**
We add the same JS line with `add` instead of `remove` to add the wanted class to the body tag: `document.querySelector("body").classList.add("class");`.

**Step 4:**
We apply changes to the class in the css

---

There of course possibilities to cut the script down. However I believe that this way is the easiest to understand and reproduce for a beginner.

```js
function textWhite() {
  document.querySelector("body").classList.remove("background-blue"); document.querySelector("body").classList.remove("background-orange"); document.querySelector("body").classList.remove("background-green");
  document.querySelector("body").classList.add("background-white");
}

function textBlue() {
document.querySelector("body").classList.remove("background-white"); document.querySelector("body").classList.remove("background-orange"); document.querySelector("body").classList.remove("background-green");
document.querySelector("body").classList.add("background-blue");
}

function textOrange() {
  document.querySelector("body").classList.remove("background-blue"); document.querySelector("body").classList.remove("background-white"); document.querySelector("body").classList.remove("background-green");
  document.querySelector("body").classList.add("background-orange");
}

function textGreen() {
document.querySelector("body").classList.remove("background-white"); document.querySelector("body").classList.remove("background-orange"); document.querySelector("body").classList.remove("background-blue");
document.querySelector("body").classList.add("background-green");
}
```

```css
.background-white {
  background-color: white;
}

.background-blue {
  background-color: blue;
}

.background-orange {
  background-color: orange;
}

.background-green {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <h2>background colors</h2>
  <div class="theme-options">
    <div onclick="textWhite()" class="theme-white">White</div>
    <div onclick="textBlue()" class="theme-blue">Blue</div>
    <div onclick="textOrange()" class="theme-orange">Orange</div>
    <div onclick="textGreen()" class="theme-green">Green</div>
  </div>
  <hr>
  <h2>text Color</h2>
  <div class="theme-options">
    <div class="theme-white">White</div>
    <div class="theme-blue">Blue</div>
    <div class="theme-orange">Orange</div>
    <div class="theme-green">Green</div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: thanks for your help but there are decorators like output and ngstyle or something else that can help me right?

Comment: decorators are part of Angular Javascript. In the end you have to program them aswell and pretty much work the same way.